# how to manage multiple war application in tomcat server?

Tags: java, maven, tomcat, servlets

I use tomcat as web server,I want to deploy many same war file in tomcat server with different config. How to do this in the best way possible manner?

So I want to run tomcat server per each war application, my means is `tomcat1` handle the `.war1` in `webapp` and ... or handle all war files with one tomcat?which one is better?

Comment: I recommend to read this http://blog.soebes.de/blog/2011/07/29/maven-configuration-for-multipe-environments/ so you can create multiple war files in one go via `mvn clean package`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the same tomcat server, but copy and rename your web application to something different. For eg, the original application name `app`, copy and rename as following.

```
    webapp -> app1
              app2
              app3
```

Running a different tomcat server for each war application might not be necessary.

Comment: thanks for fast reply @pmverma, how to stop and start each war file and config each war file when tomcat running? for example i want to change configuration for app1  (memory, and other configuration) when tomcat runnig without side effect on other application?

Comment: You need to stop and start the tomcat server. And for memory, you cannot set memory for each web application, no way, but instead you configure tomcat memory. Set `JAVA_OPTS` configuration for memory in`catalina.sh(linux) or catalina.bat(windows) `. And I am not sure what do you mean by other configuration.

Comment: thanks @pmverma , but for me it is very important factor that i can stop and start each war application without side effect, what is your solution for this problem?
thanks in advance

Comment: What do you mean by 'i can stop and start each war application', you can or you need to do so?

Comment: sorry, my means how to stop and start each war application without side effect, what is your solution?

Comment: To start and stop each application but not the whole server, you need to use Tomcat Manager. Try browsing `http://localhost:8080/manager/html`

Answer (score 3):

Change the names of your war files and deploy